# How does ACL calculate the effective permissions on a file?

Tags: linux, files, permissions, acl

I ran the following command to give the `wheel` group `rwx` permissions on new files and subdirectories created:

```
[belmin@server1]$ ls -la
total 24
drwxr-sr-x+   2 guards guards  4096 Aug 27 15:30 .
drwxr-xr-x  104 root   root   12288 Aug 27 15:19 ..

[belmin@server1]$ sudo setfacl -m d:g:wheel:rwX .

[belmin@server1]$ getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: guards
# group: guards
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:wheel:rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:wheel:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

However, when I create a file as root, I am not completely clear how the `effective` permissions are calculated:

```
[belmin@server1]$ sudo touch foo

[belmin@server1]$ getfacl foo
# file: foo
# owner: root
# group: guards
user::rw-
group::r-x                      #effective:r--
group:wheel:rwx                 #effective:rw-
group:guards:rwx                #effective:rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

Can someone elaborate on what this means?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`effective` permissions are formed by ANDing the actual (real?) permissions with the `mask`.  Since the `mask` of your file is `rw-`, all the `effective` permissions have the `x` bit turned off.

Comment: And where does the mask comes from?

Comment: So it looks like doubling: one can just set accurately real permissions instead of changing them using the mask

Answer (score 9):

Short answer:  If you want mask with the execute bit on, you must explicitly set it using `setfacl` after `touch`.  Security forbids its implicit setting.

```
setfacl -n -m m::rwx foo
```

"-n" to suppress recalculation of the mask (may not be needed).
  "m::rwx" sets the mask value to 'rwx'.  Note that "m::x" would disable all reads and writes.

---

I am unable to show why the mask is "rw-".  I assume that the default directory where `touch` creates the file remains unchanged for the entire OP example.

1. The directory entry for 'foo' should show owner 'root' (because of the sudo command and group 'guards' because the directory has the SUID bit set.  The permissions will be defaults '-rw-...r--' with the group permissions of the directory '-...r-x...' (due to the SUID bit showins as little s).
2. Next comes the ACLes, which should be the directory default.  Given that ACLs inherit, I wouldn't expect any ACLe's to created, and the ACLE mask to be the directory default, 'rwx'.

But if they are created, I would expect the new ACLe's to be primed from the default, again leaving the mask at 'rwx'.  If they are not primed from the defaults, this would seem to defeat the idea of a default ACL -- the "default" ACL would only provide named user and named group ACLes.

This now begs the question of what the mask ACLe should be.  I'd expect it to be 'rwx' from the default mask entry.  But it could be created with a blank mask, and then all sorts of legalese applies.

3. With a tentative ACL of user::rw-, group::r-x, other::r--, group:wheel:rwx, group:guards:rwx, and mask::: (unset), we consult the documentation for `setfacl`, assuming the same rules apply to file creation.

There is a clause:

> If an ACL contains named user or named group entries, and no mask entry exists, a mask entry containing the same permissions as the group entry is created.

This would set the ACL mask to "r-x", if the ACL group entry was created from the file directory entry, or "r-x" if the ACL group entry came from the default ACL.  (Ether way, for this case, the result is the same.)

There is also a clause:

> If a Default ACL contains named user entries or named group entries, and no mask entry exists, a mask entry containing the same permissions as the default Default ACL's group entry is added. ... the permissions of the mask  entry are further adjusted to include the union of all permissions affected by the mask entry.

If this rule applies, the the mask will start as "r-x" (same logic) as previous clause), and then it will be adjusted to be the "union of all permissions affected by the mask entry".

"permissions affected by the mask entry" is not defined in the `setfacl` command documentation.  The POSIX ACL documentation says:

> The mask is the combination of all access permissions of the owning group and all of the user and group entries.

Give the word "union", which is additive, I would read "combination" to be a logical or-ing.  In other words, if any group or user ACLe has "x" permission, the mask will contain "x".

4. By all this logic, the mask value in the OP's example should be 'rwx', no mater which logical path was followed.

---

The above reasoning must be flawed, as the x for execute does not appear in the mask.

Therefore, there must be some rule about how mask is calculated that has been "hidden" from common documentation sources (or we have found a bug).

My conclusion is that  the 'x' is always being unconditionally removed, and the documentation is lax.

This change was probably made on the justification of "security" -- no file shall be implicitly executable, but must have the executable bit turned on after it is created.

Comment: Check out this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165304/146978. I think it explained clearly why the 'x' bit is almost always missing.